# Is google flow secured while using on client side?

Tags: oauth, google-plus, google-oauth

Using [this example](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/) eventually I would like to send the data to my server. The question is: if someone would break client script, replace email with some other email and sand it to my server? How can it be prevented? also, according to oauth standards I should verify the data on server side using client id and secret key, but I don't see any documentation regarding that in this particular related documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You would not send unprotected data from the client to the server but you would send the access token that you've used to obtain the user info to the server side so the server side can retrieve that data from Google on its own

Answer (score 0):

You should be using what Google refers to as the [Server Side Flow](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow) (which is really more of a hybrid flow, involving both client side and server side components).

In this setup, you use the Google+ Sign-In button to navigate the OAuth handshake, but what comes back includes a very short-lived one-time-use code. Your client then sends this to your server, which exchanges it with Google's servers for an auth token, which can be used to get the email and other user information.